# -JS - Touch- prevent horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, css, touch

I need to prevent horizontal scroll in my web app. I tried with preventDefault() on touchmove event but it prevent vertical scroll too.

some idea?^^

my try:

```
    $(document).bind("touchmove", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Ok! found solution!

position FIXED on mobile devices prevent from scrolling (i have tested only on iphone).
so i change position from absolute to fixed when i need it :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see doing this is to manually code the scrolling functionality, so will start off with the above code to prevent the default functionality and then inspect the event properties to decide how to scroll the page setting window.scrollTop appropriately to vertically scroll the page.